# Changing bundle display name breaks CoreData persistent store coordinator

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Does anybody know why changing the bundle display name from `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to `Application` provokes the following CoreData error?

```
Failed to create file; code = 2
```

My `xcdatamodeld` has exactly the same name (`Application`) and the app only runs correctly if I set the bundle display to `${PRODUCT_NAME}` again. Also, the store URL has this name `@"Application.sqlite"`.

I'm changing these values under the Info.plist file.

**EDIT**

The error is in the following line

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // This line produces the error
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Beezer.sqlite"];
...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show the relevant code.

Comment: What line of code produces that error?